# Consider convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider the following series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{3^{2^n}}{2^{3^n}}$$

I believe that this series converges, but I don't know how to prove this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try the ratio test...

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=3^{2^n}/2^{3^n}$. Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n+1}/a_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}3^{2^n}4^{-3^n}=0$, from D' Alembert's theorem we know the sum of $a_n$ is convergence.